# How do you set a range of number as an errorlevel in batch?

Tags: batch-file, command, range, errorlevel

I have this script in batch and got a range of questions 1 - 12.
All my code works, but I just can't seem to find a code to throw into my batch to throw out an error message for invalid ranges selected

Example: If I choose 13, which is not part of the options, it automatically goes to 1.
I want all number from 13 up, to show "invalid option" and then default back to the choice menu.

I am not using the shift command in my batch as I just used the following code instead

```
set /p choice=Type the number that corresponds to the Step you want to take.
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0%
```

Notice the `~0` allows me to use numbers passed 9 instead of using the shift command.
Nevertheless, I need code that will say if the user type 13 or up and error appears.
Any ideas? In other words if choices are in ranges 13 - 999 show error.

***Update***

ok so, I looked at my code and realized I missed one line of code. which is

*@echo "%choice%" is not a valid selection/option*

It seems that my coding was right where I gave *'%choice%'==''* I just didnt leave an echo to say the selection was wrong. Turns out I didnt need any errorlevels in there.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: The following code will output an error statement if the choice is greater than 13, and set the inputted value to the first character entered

`@echo off`

`SET /P choice=Type the number that corresponds to the Step you want to take.`

`IF %choice% GTR 12 GOTO Error`

`ECHO You entered %choice%`

`GOTO End`

`:Error`

`ECHO %choice% is not a valid selection/option`

`set choice=%choice:~0,1%`

`ECHO %choice%`

`:End`